# Django - QuerySet - Get count for all determined child objects inside all parent objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got this model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields#

class Laptop(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields#

class Camera(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields#

class MusicPlayer(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields#
```

The last three have a foreign key associated to the Order class. *I need to retrieve via a QuerySet the summed count for each child object for all orders, grouped by each one of them.*

The result should look something like this:
**Laptop:5
Camera:10
MusicPlayer:1**

I've tried using different django queries but all I get to is retrieving the count for each order instead the count for all orders.

I know this could be easily done by just querying each one separately but I was requested to do all in one query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add related_name to your models:

```
class Laptop(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='laptops')

class Camera(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='cameras')

class MusicPlayer(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='music_players')
```

And then you can retrieve number of related models using [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#id7):

```
from django.db.models import Count

orders = Order.objects.annotate(laptops_count=Count('laptops'), cameras_count=Count('cameras'), music_players_count=Count('music_players'))
print(orders.laptops_count)
print(orders.cameras_count)
print(orders.music_players_count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Since you are trying to access laptops directly from the orders object it will return an AttributeError. This is the same problem I was having, I don't want to access all objects one by one (eg: orders[0]) to access the count.

Comment: By the way, giving the annotate values the same name as the "related_name" it return errors

Comment: You're right I fixed answer. It uses only one query, you can print query using print(orders.query) and check SQL